# CheckboxTableViewer does not change the focus of the table row when clicked on its checkbox

Tags: java, checkbox, swt, jface

Hi I am relatively new to SWT. I am using a CheckboxTableViewer. I have a listener on it:

```
diagnosesTableViewer.getTable().addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            int nomenclatureSelectionIndex = diagnosesTableViewer
                    .getTable().getSelectionIndex();
            Nomenclature checkedNomenclature = (Nomenclature) diagnosesTableViewer
                    .getElementAt(nomenclatureSelectionIndex);
            diagnosesTableViewer.setChecked(checkedNomenclature,
                    !diagnosesTableViewer
                            .getChecked(checkedNomenclature));
        }
```

When I click on the table row (anywhere but the checkbox), everything works as expected. But when I click on the checkbox specifically, I unchecks the checkbox of the previously selected row as well. I think it is because when I click on the checkbox, it does not change the focus to the new row and hence the listener is called on the old, previously selected row itlsef and the new row whose checkbox I am selecting, its listener is never being called. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CheckboxTableViewer.addCheckStateListener` to add an `ICheckStateListener` to deal with check boxes being clicked.

```
viewer.addCheckStateListener(new ICheckStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void checkStateChanged(CheckStateChangedEvent event) {
            // event.getChecked() is the check state
            // event.getElement() is element being checked/unchecked
        }
    });
```

You can select the clicked row in the event with

```
viewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(event.getElement()));
```

Use

```
IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection)viewer.getSelection();
```

to get the existing selection.

Comment: I tried doing that. The problem is that since the focus in still on the old previously selected row, the listener is called on that row too. I want to somehow remove the foucs form the old row to the new row when the checkbox is clicked.

Comment: Is there any way to see if the element is already `selected`? I dont want to call the listener again if the element is already `selected`.

Comment: Added getSelection() call